# Modifying a function to return different values

Tags: python, function, variables, return

I must modify the function gp so it will handle + and - grades by adding or subtracting 0.3 points. For example, a B + is worth 3.3 points, and a C- is 1.7 points.

Example.

```
>>> gp('A-')
3.7

>>>gp('B+')
3.3
```

The suggestion is I could just add a bunch of elif clauses to test each grade separately, but a similar design is to use a call to s.startswith to figure out the value of the letter grade, then use s.endswith to see if you should add or subtract 0.3 points.

So far this is what I have.

```
def gp(s):
       A = 4
       return A
       B = 3
       return B
       C = 2
       return C
       D = 1
       return D
       F = 0
       return f
```

Comment: You're current function won't work. The `return`s need to be conditional.

Comment: That's not even close to valid Python code.

Comment: It looks like you've made no real attempt to implement your own suggestions, so it's hard to see what you're asking.

Comment: Make a hash with the letter grades ask keys and values +-0.3.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a series of `if/elif` statements, you can store the numeric values for the grades and the suffixes in dictionaries. Also, you do not have to use `startswith` or `endswith`, you could just use `s[0]` and `s[1]` to get the first or second character in the string, after checking the length. You can also use `s[1:]` to get everything starting at the `1`th position, even if it's empty.

```
grades = {'A': 4, 'B': 3, 'C': 2, 'D': 1, 'F': 0}
signs = {'+': 0.3, '-': -0.3, '': 0}
def gp(s):
    return grades[s[0]] + signs[s[1:]]

>>> gp("A+")
4.3
>>> gp("C-")
1.7
>>> gp("F")
0
```

Comment: Isn't `s[1]` enough instead of `s[1:]`? Btw was about to post the same answer. :)

Comment: @Austin It is, but `s[1]` will fail without an additional check if no `+` or `-` is provided, whereas `s[1:]` will just return `''`.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with the `gp` function.

While it is possible to enumerate them, I suggest you read the following resources:

- [How to declare a Python function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)
- [How to use function arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions)
- [What is the purpose of the return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement)

When you're ready, I strongly recommend you use dictionaries to store your mappings. Here's an example:

```
grade_dict = dict(zip('ABCDF', (4, 3, 2, 1, 0)))
sign_dict = dict(zip('-+', (-0.3, 0.3)))

def gp(s):

    grade, *sign = s

    if sign:
        return grade_dict[grade] + sign_dict[sign[0]]
    else:
        return grade_dict[grade]

res = gp('A-')  # 3.7
```

**Edit**: My schooling didn't involve GPA, so I didnt't catch this. If you need to cap at 4.0, you can use this modification:

```
def gp(s):

    grade, *sign = s

    if sign:
        res = grade_dict[grade] + sign_dict[sign[0]]
    else:
        res = grade_dict[grade]

    return max(res, 4.0)
```

Comment: @ChristianDean, Thanks for the feedback. Hopefully, it's a little clearer now.

Comment: Yeah, @jpp, that looks nice! I forgot to when I made my comment earlier, so +1!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use a dictionary for how many points each specific grade would get. Using a dictionary is somewhat like the Python equivalent for a `switch` statement and is generally consider more idiomatic than a long `if/elif/else` chain. (My answer is assuming you're using the standard 4.0 GPA calculation scale. If not, this can obviously be changed to suite your needs.)

```
grade_to_points = {
    'A+':   4.0,
    'A':    4.0,
    'A-':   3.7,
    'B+':   3.3,
    'B':    3.0,
    ...
}

def gp(grade):
    points = grade_to_points.get(grade)
    if points is None:
        raise ValueError('{:r} is not a valid grade!'.format(grade))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use dictionnaries

```
def function(grade)
  dict = {'A':4, 'B':3, 'C':2, 'D':1, 'F':0}
  if grade[1] == '+':
    return dict[grade[0]]+0.3
  elif grade[1] == '-':
    return dict[grade[0]] - 0.3
```

Then add or substract 0.3 depending on the sign

Comment: This fails if there is no `+` or `-` at all.

Comment: @tobias_k it's also missing a colon and capitalisation is wrong

Comment: It was just an example, he asked for a method

Answer (score 0):

Another dictionary (hash) approach.

```
def gp(s):
    gradhash = {
        "A+": 4.0 + 0.3
        ,"A": 4.0
        ,"A-": 4.0 - 0.3
        ,"B+": 3.0 + 0.3
        ,"B": 3.0
        ,"B-": 3.0 - 0.3
        ,"C+": 2.0 + 0.3
        ,"C": 2.0
        ,"C-": 2.0 - 0.3
        ,"D+": 1.0 + 0.3
        ,"D": 1.0
        ,"D-": 1.0 - 0.3
    }

    return gradhash[s]

print(gp('A-'))
```